Alternative to auth0/auth0-react due to dumb hardcoded urls to connect/oauth/token instead of using openid-configuration
As I understand problem is well-known but strange thing that it is not solved yet.
auth0/auth0-react is using under the hood auth0-spa-js which is using hardcoded url to fetch bearer tokens: like POST to /connect/oauth/token.
But in my case it should go to /connect/token instead as it is configured on my identity server (duende) here: .well-known/openid-configuration
If it's not solvable problem - what alternative auth0 client library I can use instead (for react or for nextjs) ? Which should be doing proper thing to fetch config from .well-known/openid-configuration and grab proper urls and have properly implemented
authorization code flow with PCKE.

Have a look at Stytch.  Stytch is infrastructure for developers to build auth into applications. Stytch provides a suite of dev tools, including APIs, SDKs, UI components, tailored to support user & org management for a wide range of architectures & use cases.
